# What price does Runeloader report back when examining an item?

Tags: oldschool-runescape

Using the Runeloader client, when you examine an item, it reports back to you the Grand Exchange average price.  I was killing some Mutated Bloodvelds in the Catacombs of Kourend, which can drop [Mithril Full Helmets](https://oldschool.runescape.wiki/w/Mithril_full_helm).  When I examined them in game, I get this reported back:

[image: Examine Info]

According to that picture, the helmet is worth around 3.7k gold.  However, when I got to the Grand Exchange, it traded for about 800 coins, which is more reflective of the price listed on the Wiki page (linked above).

This isn't the first time I've ran into this issue either.  It's happened with other items. What price exactly is Runeloader reporting back?

Comment: I don't play OSRS or use Ruleloader, but I'm going to assume this is a bug. I would [report a bug](https://www.runeloader.com/forum/forum-39.html) on their forum. I would also make sure that your client is fully updated.

Comment: Do you have any extra mithril full helms in your bank or inventory? [This](https://www.runeloader.com/forum/thread-1152.html) thread, posted back in July, states *Now shows stack value when examining and item in your inventory or bank*. Not sure if that is the issue, but it's a start

Comment: @Wondercricket yes I had I think 3 or 4.  I thought the stack prices was for items that stack only though such as arrows, throwing knives, etc.  When you examine a stacked item, it will actually say something like "Stack Value: #."  I'm not sure if having multiple items that aren't stacked sum up to this total.

Comment: @Timmy Jim You're probably right on that. Given it's been a long time since I've played, I completely forgot about how stacked items worked. If that's the case, then probably a bug. Go play same Pest Control ;)